# Redirecting to an aspx.page using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, redirect

I want to redirect to an aspx page using javascript but upon attemptin this I get the following error

```
uncaught type error. Property 'location'of object[object global] is not a function
```

How cab I redirect to a aspx page using javascript

```
function SearchContent() {

var txtBoxValue = $('#txtSearch').val();  
if (txtBoxValue == "") {
    alert("Please enter a value");
    return false;
}
window.location("SearchResults?search="+txtBoxValue);
```

Comment: window.location isn't a function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location for references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
location.href = "SearchResults?search="+txtBoxValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

please try `window.location.href = "SearchResults?search="+txtBoxValue;`

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
location.replace("SearchResults?search="+txtBoxValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check

**ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('You are redirecting...');window.location='Yourpage.aspx';", true);**

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.NET MVC

You can also do try this:

```
var parameter= $("#parameter_id").val();
```

1. When you want to call another action from the curent controller:

   ```
   location.href = ("actionName?parameter=" + parameter);
   ```
2. When you want to call a action from another controller:

   ```
   location.windows= ("~/controllerName/actionName?parameter=" + parameter);
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That code must be placed between the <script> </script> tags