# Redirect from asp.net page to another using javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, response.redirect

I know that if I want to redirect from asp.net page to anther in code behind I need to write-

```
Response.Redirect("SomePage.aspx");
```

My question is if is it possible to do the same thing in javascript function, and if it is so how?

thank you!

Comment: have you done any research at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jumping to a new HTML page with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442384/jumping-to-a-new-html-page-with-javascript)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874481/redirecting-to-an-aspx-page-using-javascript

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This should do:

```
window.location = "SomePage.aspx";
```

or

```
window.location.href="SomePage.aspx";
```

or

```
window.location.assign("SomePage.aspx");
```

Comment: old post but how would you add a 5 sec timer onto this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "onclick", "javascript:window.open( 'SomePage.aspx','_blank','height=600px,width=600px,scrollbars=1');", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
window.location.href = 'page.aspx';
```

I dont know if is the best way